# Extracting the payload from an existing PCAP to identify any cleartext

Tags: python, scapy

I need a function that can extract the payload to identify whether any plaintext is within any HTTP packets.

The code below extracts the payload from a PCAP file however it seems it actually sniffs the first 1000 and then extract the payload.

How would I go about rewriting this so that I parse an existing PCAP rather than sniff and extract the payload on the go

`os.system(tshark  -T fields -e _ws.col.Info -e http -e frame.time -e "data.data -w WeMo_Data.pcap > WeMo_Data.txt -c     1000");`

```
import os
from kamene.all import *
import subprocess

#Imported module 
from getHTTPHeaders import HTTPHeaders, extractText

data = "WeMo.pcap"
a = rdpcap(data)

os.system(tshark  -T fields -e _ws.col.Info -e http -e frame.time -e "data.data -w Eavesdrop_Data.pcap > Eavesdrop_Data.txt -c     1000");

sessions = a.sessions()
carved_texts = 1
for session in sessions:
    http_payload = ""
    for packet in sessions[session]:
        try:
            if packet[TCP].dport == 80 or packet[TCP].sport == 80:
                http_payload += str(packet[TCP].payload)
        except:
            pass
        headers = HTTPHeaders(http_payload)
    if headers is None:
        continue
    text = extractText(headers,http_payload)
    if text is not None:
         print (text)
```

Here are the other 2 functions that I imported

```
import re
import zlib

def HTTPHeaders(http_payload):
    try:
        # isolate headers
        headers_raw = http_payload[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n") + 2]
        regex = ur"(?:[\r\n]{0,1})(\w+\-\w+|\w+)(?:\ *:\ *)([^\r\n]*)(?:[\r\n]{0,1})"
        headers = dict(re.findall(regex, headers_raw, re.UNICODE))
        print headers
        return headers
    except:
        return None
    if 'Content-Type' not in headers:
        return None
    return headers

def extractText(headers, http_payload):
        text = None
        try:
            if 'text/plain' in headers['Content-Type']:
                text = http_payload[http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+4:]
                try:
                    if "Accept-Encoding" in headers.keys():
                        if headers['Accept-Encoding'] == "gzip":
                            text = zlib.decompress(text,  16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
                    elif headers['Content-Encoding'] == "deflate":
                        text = zlib.decompress(text)
                except: pass
        except:
            return None
        return text
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you sure this can run? `os.system(tshark  -T fields...` looks problematic.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is so that you reduce your code to the relevant parts of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you did there (https://medium.com/@vworri/extracting-the-payload-from-a-pcap-file-using-python-d938d7622d71)

Though honnestly this article isn't great. What I'd advise you to do is to simply use [Scapy 2.4.3 and enable HTTP](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html) decoding using
`from scapy.layers.http import *`
or
`load_layers("http")`

You could just then do

```
for sess in sniff(offline="WeMo.pcap", session=TCPSession).sessions().values():
    for packet in sess:
        # Use TCPSession to automatically rebuild HTTP packets
        if HTTP in packet and Raw in packet:
            # packet is HTTP and has payload
            http_payload = packet[Raw]
```

Basically all you have to do is remove the part where it calls tshark... you probably should take the time to understand the code you copy pasted :P

Comment: Thanks for the advice....I am newbie in Python but working on this project...I did try just removing the tshark but this did not work...I tried what you have suggested which does print out the raw packets..How do I put this in a readable format?